# How to share internet through wifi

Tags: networking, 16.04

in windows I use the netsh wlan command.
how I can use it in ubuntu 16.10

Answer (score -1):

Plug your computer via ethernet and then make  anew connection as a HotSpot. **Use this images as guides.**

[image: One]

[image]